# Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s)

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, setx

I am having trouble understanding why I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
```

Implementation

```
C:\Users>setx JAVA_HOME "C:\DOC\JDK64\1.8.0.74"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

C:\Users>setx PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.

C:\Users>setx PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%bin"
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
```

Comment: It means it has already has been added. Also with setx you just add the folder you want added. EG `setx path c:\fred` **adds** fred to the existing path if it's not already present. In short ignore the error. To hide it suffix `> nul` to the command.

Answer (score 6):

It is quite simple but hidden.
run setx /? and I suppose the answer is there.
The PATH you give as a parameter (string) contains space/spaces.
You should enclose the PTH between "".

Comment: I don't see extra spaces nor missing quotes

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by invisible chars (check for hidden <kbd>TAB</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your bat file in Notepad++, not windows notepad. You may see invisible whitespaces which should not be there.

Answer (score -1):

i try to set enviroment with powershell it works, but in cmd it throws that erro

```
setx path "%path%;D:\edge_download\geckodriver-v0.33.0-win64/geckodriver.exe"
```